# Unresolved class name proguard-rules Android Studio 4.0

Tags: android, proguard, android-studio-4.0

When I update to Android Studio 4.0 proguard-rules it shows warning `Unresolved class name`. Below is example but I sure it still waring the exist class in my project.

```
-keep class com.squareup.haha.** { *; }
-keep class com.squareup.leakcanary.** { *; }
```

If I change from `**` to `*` this warning is gone.

```
-keep class com.squareup.haha.* { *; }
-keep class com.squareup.leakcanary.* { *; }
```

Does anyone get this? Should I ignore this warning or it's bug of Android Studio 4.0?

**Update**

I find it's bug, it already assigned but not resolved https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/153616200

**Update July**

Google team already analysis and increase priory of this bug, it may be related to a newer version of R8.

**Update August**

Fixed in `AS 4.2 Canary 9`

Comment: add it as an answer and mark it as accepted

Answer (score 17):

> Check this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147802433
>
> `If you right-click on error, there is option "suppress for statement", after that AS adds a comment such as:
>
> ## noinspection ShrinkerUnresolvedReference

-keep class not.existing

And with this comment there is no error for "not.existing".`

[image]

Comment: Actually we only need `noinspection`  when the library change and the class doesn't exits but some class and model is exits but android studio 4.0 still said it's unresolved. I think it should be bug instead of fix by "suppress for statement"

Answer (score 11):

Replace `.**` with `**` as workaround. No compile error and classes are kept.

```
-keep class com.squareup.haha** { *; }
-keep class com.squareup.leakcanary** { *; }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This issue is fixed in Android Studio 4.2 Canary 8. Please find the release notes here https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2020/08/android-studio-42-canary-8-available.html and check for this issue id **#153616200**

Answer (score 1):

A folder and its subfile. I have tested this:

```
com.xx.xx.* { *; }
```

I guess that it may contain multiply folders and subfile. I've not tested this:

```
com.xx.xx.**.* {*;}
```

Answer (score 1):

All of these answers are mere non-sense because:

LeakCanary is being added as `debugImplementation`.

- it makes no sense to have rules for classes which do not exist in `release` builds.
- it makes even less sense to obfuscate `debug` builds.

In case you may require any of these rules, you've added it to the wrong build-type.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
.**
```

with

```
.*.*
```

result

```
-keep class com.squareup.haha.*.* { *; }
-keep class com.squareup.leakcanary.*.* { *; }
```

Comment: This is not solution dear, you can also use by remove single star 
** replace with *, but this is not a solution this bug

Comment: this works. unresolved class name errors now disappear.

Comment: .** means the directory and all subdirectories, recursive.  .*.* means the directory and its immediate subdirectories only.  They are not equivalent

Comment: It's not a solution. If a traffic light is stuck on red, you can fix it by making it hang on orange or green instead. Nobody will complain (for a while), but it isn't fixed. On some junctions it might work, on others you'll cause crashes.