# Unresolved class name warning in proguard android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, proguard

I have encountered this error in my proguard rule.

The message is displaying here Unresolved class name.

[image]

Comment: What's inside `Interface` and `helper` packages?

Comment: There are interface and class that support the main file. Unable tofirebase database communication error. that why i use you exclude this?

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62080165/unresolved-class-name-proguard-rules-android-studio-4-0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unresolved class name proguard-rules Android Studio 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62080165/unresolved-class-name-proguard-rules-android-studio-4-0)